# How to implement Page Object Models using context browser in Playwright in typescript?

Tags: javascript, constructor, e2e-testing, playwright

This current implementation is working very well for certain classes

```
export class PlaywrightDevPage {
  readonly page: Page;

  constructor(page: Page) {
    this.page = page;
  }

  async goto() {
    await this.page.goto('https://playwright.dev');
  }
}
```

```
test('test using page with page object model', async ({ page }) => {
  const devPage = new PlaywrightDevPage(page);

  await devPage.goto();
});
```

But I want to implement a new context in the Page Object Models, but the browser is closed when the object is created.

```
export class AppPage {
  readonly browser: Browser;

  constructor(browser: Browser) {
    this.browser = browser;
  }

  async goto() {
    // Remove storage state to simplify the sample,
    // the main problem is with browser.newContext: Browser has been closed
    // const context = await this.browser.newContext({
    //   storageState: './auth.json',
    // });
    const context = await this.browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://playwright.dev');
  }
}
```

```
  test('test using context with page object model', async ({ browser }) => {
  const devPage = new AppPage(browser);

  devPage.goto();
});
```

It is throwing the following error:

> browser.newContext: Browser has been closed

What is the way to implement context in Page Object Models?

[Live sample in stackblitz that is showing the error.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jfgreffier-try-playwright-test-vfqvm5?file=tests%2Fexample.spec.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your top example,

```js
test('test sample', async ({page}) => {
  devPage = await new PlaywrightDevPage(page);
  devPage.goto();
});
```

should be

```js
test('test sample', async ({page}) => {
  const devPage = new PlaywrightDevPage(page);
  await devPage.goto();
});
```

Your constructor isn't `async`, so there's no promise to `await`. However, `devPage.goto()` is `async` and should be `await`ed.

In your second example, you're passing a `browser` as a `page`. That's the wrong object. You can destructure the `browser` in the test block callback and use that if you want:

```js
test('test sample', async ({browser}) => {
  const devPage = new AppPage(browser);
  await devPage.goto();
});
```

Modify the class to keep track of `context` and `page` so you can use them in other functions and eventually close them (and ensure `this.page` exists when you run `this.page.goto`):

```js
export class AppPage {
  readonly browser: Browser;

  constructor(browser: Browser) {
    this.browser = browser;
  }

  async goto() {
    this.context = await this.browser.newContext({
      storageState: './auth.json',
    });
    this.page = await this.context.newPage();
    await this.page.goto('https://playwright.dev');
  }
}
```

As a possible design improvement, it might make sense to create a separate function that handles creating context and the page. It's a little odd that `goto` is responsible for these things, breaking the single-responsibility principle.

Comment: Sorry for the await error in the object creation, I can reproduce the error in the stackbliz.

Comment: Resolved adding the changes that you provided https://stackblitz.com/edit/jfgreffier-try-playwright-test-vfqvm5?file=tests%2Fexample.spec.ts

Comment: Random question: How come no `browser.Launch` is required in this case? Does playwright test handle browser.launch automatically?

Comment: @msmith1114 I don't think `browser.launch` is part of the API. Did you mean [`browserType.launch`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsertype#browser-type-launch)? If so, yes, Playwright handles that for you.

Comment: @ggorlen Sorry yes that's what I meant. I guess the "test" handles this right? IE: if you don't use a library then you need to manually launch it correct?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "don't use a library?" Playwright is a library. Are you referring to tests specifically? Then, yes, without using Playwright tests, you'll need to launch and close the browser yourself. Taking a step back, there's a pretty easy test here: try running the code. If the browser launches, then you can assume the test suite has done it for you. If not, launch it manually. If there's ongoing confusion, I suggest installing Playwright, then running a test and working through a "getting started" tutorial. I think it'll resolve some confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You could try passing in the `browser` from the test fixture and then use that in your page.

```
test('test sample', async ({browser, page}) => {
  const appPage = new AppPage(browser);
  await appPage.goto();
});
```

Comment: I am passing browser in the constructor, I added the sample error in a stackblitz

Comment: Resolved adding the changes that you provided https://stackblitz.com/edit/jfgreffier-try-playwright-test-vfqvm5?file=tests%2Fexample.spec.ts

Comment: I suggest `appPage =` be `const appPage =`. No need to globally scope this variable.