# How to assign async methods in the constructor in playwright implemetation?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, constructor, playwright

I have a Page Object Model that is handling browser specification but when I tried to assign a new context from browser and assign to page is not working as expected because is an async method this way is not possible to create the object without initialize with a method after the object creation.

Is possible to assing async value in the constructor?

What is the best pattern?

```
export class AppPage {
  readonly browser: Browser;
  readonly page: Page;
  readonly context: BrowserContext;

  public currentPage: Page;


  constructor(browser: Browser) {
    this.browser = browser;
    // Is not possible to assign in the constructor because these are async methods
    // this.context = await this.browser.newContext();
    // this.page = await context.newPage();
  }

  async initialize() {
    const context = await this.browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
    // Is requiring to call an extra method in order ot initialized
    this.currentPage = page;
  }

  async goto() {
    await this.currentPage.goto('https://playwright.dev');
  }
}
```

This is the current implementation is required to initialize the page assingation.

```
test('test using context with page object model', async ({ browser }) => {
  const app = new AppPage(browser);
  await app.initialize();

  await app.goto();
});
```

[Stackblitz live sample.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jfgreffier-try-playwright-test-5gpxbz?file=tests%2Fexample.spec.ts)

Comment: As discussed in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75756331/6243352), don't forget to keep track of `this.context` so you can close it later. Have you read through [Async/Await Class Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431550/async-await-class-constructor)? Much ink has been spilled on this topic already (341k views, 24 answers, many ideas and patterns to consider). What are your goals/concerns here? Do you have to use a class or can you write a custom function(s)? You could return `this` from the `initialize` func and chain it in one line.

Comment: See also [Is it bad practice to have a constructor function return a Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398699/is-it-bad-practice-to-have-a-constructor-function-return-a-promise)

Comment: Perhaps what you're looking for is something like [global setup and teardown](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-advanced#global-setup-and-teardown)

Comment: Make `initialise` a `static` method that returns a promise for a new instance.

Comment: The best way to implement in Plawright is using the configuration. That is provided by the framework export default: defineConfig({
  use: {
    storageState: 'state.json',
  },
});. https://stackblitz.com/edit/jfgreffier-try-playwright-test-vhkqb7?file=playwright.config.ts,tests%2Fexample.spec.ts

Comment: With this configuration is easy use page and avoid initialize method. constructor(page: Page) {
    this.page = page;
  }

Answer (score 1):

One way to tackle this, is to let the constructor store a promise for the initialisation part and then every other method must await that promise first. This means that `context` and `currentPage` are no longer properties of your instance, but are the resolution values of the above promise. They can of course be retrieved from that promise multiple times, but always asynchronously.

```
export class AppPage {
  readonly browser: Browser;

  constructor(browser: Browser) {
    this.browser = browser;
    this.ready = this.initialize();
  }

  async initialize() {
    const context = await this.browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
    return {context, page};
  }

  async goto() {
    const {page} = await this.ready;
    await page.goto('https://playwright.dev');
  }

  async close() {
    const {context} = await this.ready;
    await context.close();
  }
}
```

The test script can now omit the call to `initialize`:

```
test('test using context with page object model', async ({ browser }) => {
  const app = new AppPage(browser);
  await app.goto();
});
```

Comment: The best way to implement in Plawright is using the configuration. That is provided by the framework.